# `to_a` avoid rerun a query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I notices in the console an unusual user of `to_a` method in `ActiveRecord_Relation`. I'll reproduce it below:

Selecting from a table to the variable `a`:

```
a = Crypto::ExchangeQuotation.all
[DEBUG]   Crypto::ExchangeQuotation Load (121.1ms)  SELECT  "crypto_exchange_quotations".* FROM "crypto_exchange_quotations" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

Calling `a`:

```
2.4.1 :003 > a
[DEBUG]   Crypto::ExchangeQuotation Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "crypto_exchange_quotations".* FROM "crypto_exchange_quotations" LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

`a` to array:

```
2.4.1 :004 > a.to_a
[DEBUG]   Crypto::ExchangeQuotation Load (0.9ms)  SELECT "crypto_exchange_quotations".* FROM "crypto_exchange_quotations"
```

Calling `a` again:

```
2.4.1 :005 > a
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Crypto::ExchangeQuotation id: 1, exchange_code: "ARN", base_currency_code: "BRL", currency_code: "BTC", origin: "bitvalor", created_at: "2018-03-15 23:24:06", updated_at: "2018-03-15 23:24:06", buy: 17810.0, sell: 17810.0>,
```

Calling `to_a` in the variable, calling it again after is really avoiding rerun the query again? If yes, why? Because what is returned in `a` still is an `ActiveRecord_Relation`.

Comment: I think its on purpose: you could pass `a` as a base scope to another query so it must remain a Relation. Yet, ActiveRecord has cache in production so it should do the trick. You could do `a = a.to_a` if you really want to change the variable

Comment: I see. Supose that I have an `a` in production with a heavy query, and I need to use it in some places of a method: it's a good strategy I call `a.to_a` after I store the query in `a` to use it in sequence?

Comment: rwehresmann it could be a very wrong strategy. If you want to fetch baches of data use find_each at the end of query. But all depends of context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `to_a` is not mutating base object, but it is duplicating this and returning it as an array. Here look ad code of to_a:

```
def to_a
  records.dup
end
```

To really change it to array you have to override variable a

```
a = a.to_a
```